Make the first segment 5 seconds, the next 10/FFMPEG
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i /144.mp4 \
       -r 25 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -profile:v main \
       -keyint_min 250 -g 250 -sc_threshold 0 \
       -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 \
       -map v:0 -filter:v:0 "scale=-2:144" -b:v:0 448k\
       -map 0:a \
       -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
       -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
       -dash_segment_type mp4 \
       -use_template 1 \
       -use_timeline 0 \
       -seg_duration 10 \
       -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
       -f dash \
       /s/dash.mpd

Is it possible to make it so that the starting (initial segment is 5 seconds) and the subsequent ones are 10 seconds each?
I think a shorter starting segment will reduce response time, and will be lighter in weight...
